# Broadcom BCM4360 not working after software update

Tags: drivers, 18.04, broadcom

I'm running ubuntu 18.04 and have not had any issues with my wifi until a recent software update caused my wifi to disappear.  I've tried purging and reinstalling bcmwl-kernel-source and rebooting several times, and tried installing specific drivers for the card, but to no avail.  I've verified secure boot is still off.

Here's the results of

```
➜  ~ lshw -C network

WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df400000-df407fff memory:df200000-df3fffff
```

And:

```
➜  ~ inxi -Fxz                                            
System:    Host: austin-desktop Kernel: 5.3.0-22-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.4.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu4) Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: ASRock model: Z370 Extreme4 serial: N/A
           UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: P1.80 date: 03/20/2018
CPU:       6 core Intel Core i7-8700K (-MT-MCP-) arch: Skylake rev.10 cache: 12288 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 44398
           clock speeds: max: 4700 MHz 1: 4383 MHz 2: 4381 MHz 3: 4399 MHz 4: 4337 MHz 5: 4335 MHz 6: 4360 MHz
           7: 4398 MHz 8: 4392 MHz 9: 4388 MHz 10: 4385 MHz 11: 4383 MHz 12: 4386 MHz
Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA GP106 [GeForce GTX 1060 6GB] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: nvidia (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz, 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2 version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.31 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card-1 NVIDIA GP106 High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 01:00.1
           Card-2 Intel 200 Series PCH HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Card-3 C-Media driver: USB Audio usb-ID: 001-003
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k5.3.0-22-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V driver: e1000e v: 3.2.6-k bus-ID: 00:1f.6
           IF: enp0s31f6 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter bus-ID: 09:00.0
           IF: N/A state: N/A mac: N/A
           Card-3: Realtek RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: r8188eu v: v4.1.4_6773.20130222 usb-ID: 001-004
           IF: wlx503eaa6eda9f state: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 17001.7GB (22.5% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: MR9266 size: 12000.7GB
           ID-2: /dev/nvme0n1 model: Samsung_SSD_960_EVO_500GB size: 500.1GB
           ID-3: /dev/sdb model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 500.1GB
           ID-4: /dev/sdc model: WDC_WD40EZRZ size: 4000.8GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 458G used: 252G (59%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 0.0:55C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 344 Uptime: 0 min Memory: 1563.0/64257.5MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.4.0
           Client: Shell (zsh 5.4.2) inxi: 2.3.56
```

And:

```
➜  ~ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0619]
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

Any ideas?  Thank you in advance!

**Edit:**

Apparently a recent kernel update broke bcmwl.  There's a fix [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/dp6vlc/bcmwlkernelsource_doesnt_work_with_new_kernel/), unfortunately it didn't work for me and I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `5.3` kernel is not officially supported on Ubuntu-18.04 yet. You installed this kernel manually or using `linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge` package.

That's why the `bcmwl-kernel-source` from `bionic` repo doesn't build on your system.

That can be fixed by installing a patched `bcmwl-kernel-source` from a corresponding to the kernel version non-LTS release. In this case `eoan`.

You can download and install the package from the `eoan` repository.
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb